# Why does ack over ssh not work?

Tags: bash, ssh, grep, ack

I've got a simple bash script to remove some folders on a remote server over ssh. It basically does this:

```
THE_HOST=12.34.56.78
ssh me@$THE_HOST "rm /the/file/path/thefile.zip"
```

This works perfectly well. Before I do this I often search the contents of the files in a folder for a string using [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/):

```
ack thestring /the/folder/path/
```

This works perfect when I ssh into the server and run it, but when I use it in one command it doesn't work:

```
ssh me@$THE_HOST "ack thestring /the/folder/path/"
```

This seems to freeze or run forever: I get no output and the command never ends. Does anybody know why this doesn't work for ack?

Comment: What do you mean with "it is not working?" You do not receive any output, you receive an error?

Comment: Could be ack behaves differently when it is run in a terminal. Try `ssh -t me@$THE_HOST "ack thestring /the/folder/path/`"`

Comment: @kvantour - Forgot to add that. I added it to the question: It seems to freeze or run forever: I get no output and the command never ends.

Comment: @nos - Yes, that's it, thank you! If you add you comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: It would be nice to know why this is the case. I searched a bit, but I could not find anything why it is not working.

Comment: just throwing this in: if you try to use `ack` with `ansible` (ad-hoc) command - it doesn't work with the "shell" module, but works with the "raw" module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be ack behaves differently when it is run in a terminal. Try using the -t argument

```
ssh -t me@$THE_HOST "ack thestring /the/folder/path/"
```

When ack detects that stdin is not a terminal(a tty device), it will attempt to read the text to search in from stdin instead of the given file/folder. That's what happens when you run it through ssh, stdin will be connected to the ssh connection, which does not look like a terminal(tty) to ack.

The -t argument to `ssh`  instead allocates a tty and connects it to stdin/out of the program you run, ack will then think it runs in a terminal and instead use the file/folder argument for searching.
See http://github.com/beyondgrep/ack2/issues/659

Comment: Maybe because ack uses the Term module in Perl to output ANSI color sequences? Maybe you could try `ANSI_COLORS_DISABLED=1 ack thestring /the/folder/path/`